# Where the memory to the variable returned by library function is allocated

Tags: c, linux, memory, glibc

In the following program

```
int main(){
char * time;
struct tm timeptr;
t.tm_sec = 10;
t.tm_min = 10;
t.tm_hour = 6;
t.tm_mday = 25;
t.tm_mon = 2;
t.tm_year = 89;
t.tm_wday = 6;
time = asctime(&timeptr);
puts(time);
}
```

Where the memory to string returned by asctime() is allocated? I mean is it allocated in heap or caller/called function's stack or where else? if its in heap then do I need to free it? if its in the asctime's stack how it is accessible to me even if the function has returned the control to me? if its in caller function's stack how did it not corrupt any data of the callers stack?All I understood is it has to be allocated in user space.

Comment: What reference on `asctime` doesn't mention this?

Comment: Down in the Return Value section of [the documentation of `asctime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime) you'll likely find your answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig found the answer

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is calculated from the static area; it's not Heap.
hence, subsequent calls to asctime would modify the string pointed by an earlier returned pointer. No need to free the returned pointer.

Comment: does that mean the memory will get freed only when program dies or gets killed

Comment: Yes, static memory free when program dies or gets killed

Answer (score 0):

In the `asctime` documentation at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime) says:

> Return value
>   pointer to a static null-terminated character string holding the textual representation of date and time. The string may be shared between `asctime` and `ctime`, and may be overwritten on each invocation of any of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

`asctime` returns a pointer to a string.

There are two possible questions that can be asked.

1. Where the pointer is allocated?
2. Where is the pointed-to string is allocated?

The answers are:

1. Where the compiler writer decides to allocate it (normally in a register, but for larger return types it could be on the stack).
2. Where the function writer decides to allocate it. It could reasonably be either a static array or a heap-allocated array. In order to know, you need to read the function documentation. For `asctime` it's a static arrray. For other functions it may be something else.